# Custom jQuery Image Slider Not Working

Tags: jquery, loops, slider

Having problems getting any of my images to show up.

**JQUERY**

```
function slider() {
var slideIndex = 1;
var slideLength = $('#slider').length();
function slide() {
    if (slideIndex < 1) {
        slideIndex = (slideLength - 1);
    }

    if (slideIndex > slideLength) {
        slideIndex = 1;
    }

    $('#slider:nth-child(' + slideIndex + ')').css({
        opacity: 0
    });
    $('#slider:nth-child(' + (slideLength + 1) + ')').css({
        opacity: 1
    })
}
if (!$('#slider').is(':hover')) {
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        slideIndex++;
        slide();
    });
}

$('.home_img_slider_btn_left').on('click', function () {
    slideIndex--;
    slide();
});
$('.home_img_slider_btn_right').on('click', function () {
    slideIndex++;
    slide();
});
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div style="" id="home_container">
    <div class="page_title">
        <i></i>Home
    </div>
    <div class="home_img_slider_container">
        <div class="home_img_slider">
            <div class="home_img_slider_btn_left">
                <img src="files/img/icon-arrow-left.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="slider">
                <img title="Eaglespeed" class="home_img_slider_img one" src="files/img/eaglespeed-corner.jpg" />
                <img title="Eaglespeed" class="home_img_slider_img two" src="files/img/eaglespeed.jpg" />
                <img title="Eaglespeed" class="home_img_slider_img three" src="files/img/eaglespeed-front.jpg" />
                <img title="Eaglespeed" class="home_img_slider_img four" src="files/img/eaglespeed-giants.jpg" />
                <img title="Eaglespeed" class="home_img_slider_img five" src="files/img/eaglespeed-sign.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="home_img_slider_btn_right">
                <img src="files/img/icon-arrow-right.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.home_img_slider_container {
width: 90%;
margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
}

.home_img_slider_btn_left, .home_img_slider_btn_right {
cursor: pointer;
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
top: calc(50% - 50px);
background-color: #c2f8ff;
border-radius: 50%;
-moz-transition: opacity .5s ease, top .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
-o-transition: opacity .5s ease, top .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease, top .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
transition: opacity .5s ease, top .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
z-index: 3;
}

.home_img_slider_btn_left {
left: 10px;
}

.home_img_slider_btn_left:hover {
    background-color: rgba(194, 248, 255, 0.50);
}

.home_img_slider_btn_left img {
    height: 50px;
}

.home_img_slider {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 800px;
height: 600px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid #1F242A;
}

#slider img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.home_img_slider:hover .home_img_slider_btn_left, .home_img_slider:hover .home_img_slider_btn_right {
    opacity: 1;
    top: calc(50% - 25px);
}

.home_img_slider_btn_right {
right: 10px;
}

.home_img_slider_btn_right:hover {
    background-color: rgba(194, 248, 255, 0.50);
}

.home_img_slider_btn_right img {
    height: 50px;
}
```

None of the images are showing up, or transitioning so, I've spent hours trying to figure this out. I believe it has something to do with it automatically transitioning the first time, and then it can't switch after that.

**Update 1** 
I reviewed my code after the first response, and changed .animate to .css, realizing I was changing the pictures' opacity in reverse order. Still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var slideIndex = 1;
    var slideLength = $('#slider > img').size();
    var timer;
    
    function slide() {
        if (slideIndex < 0) {
            slideIndex = (slideLength - 1);
        }
    
        if (slideIndex >= slideLength) {
            slideIndex = 0;
        }
        
        $('#slider > img').hide().animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 200);
        $('#slider > img').eq(slideIndex).show().animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 200);
    }
    
    function change(){
        timer = setInterval(function () {
        slideIndex++;
        slide();
    },1000);
    }
    
    if (!$('.home_img_slider_container').is(':hover')) {
        change();
    }
    
    $('.home_img_slider_container').mouseover(function(){
     clearInterval(timer);
    }).mouseout (function(){
         change();
    });
    
    $('.home_img_slider_btn_left').on('click', function () {
        slideIndex--;
        slide();
    });
    $('.home_img_slider_btn_right').on('click', function () {
        slideIndex++;
        slide();
    });
    
});
```

```css
.home_img_slider_container {
width: 200px;
margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
}

.home_img_slider_btn_left, .home_img_slider_btn_right {
cursor: pointer;
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
top: calc(50% - 50px);
background-color: #c2f8ff;
border-radius: 50%;
-moz-transition: opacity .5s ease, top .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
-o-transition: opacity .5s ease, top .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease, top .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
transition: opacity .5s ease, top .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
z-index: 3;
}

.home_img_slider_btn_left {
left: 10px;
}

.home_img_slider_btn_left:hover {
    background-color: rgba(194, 248, 255, 0.50);
}

.home_img_slider_btn_left img {
    height: 50px;
}

.home_img_slider {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid #1F242A;
}

#slider img {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    display:none;
}

.home_img_slider:hover .home_img_slider_btn_left, .home_img_slider:hover .home_img_slider_btn_right {
    opacity: 1;
    top: calc(50% - 25px);
}

.home_img_slider_btn_right {
right: 10px;
}

.home_img_slider_btn_right:hover {
    background-color: rgba(194, 248, 255, 0.50);
}

.home_img_slider_btn_right img {
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="" id="home_container">
    <div class="page_title">
        <i></i>Home
    </div>
    <div class="home_img_slider_container">
        <div class="home_img_slider">
            <div class="home_img_slider_btn_left">
                <img src="http://www.mricons.com/store/png/121768_40595_32_arrow_left_icon.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="slider">
                                
                <img title="Eaglespeed" src="http://glamorouslymommy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/small-background1.jpg" />
                
                 <img title="Eaglespeed"  src="http://images.neopets.com/ncmall/claw/popups/bg.png" />
                
                <img title="Eaglespeed"  src="http://botanical.bg/en/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/400px-Organic-Logo.svg_.png" />
                
            </div>
            <div class="home_img_slider_btn_right">
                <img src="http://cdn-img.easyicon.net/png/10967/1096749.gif" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've now got the slider working almost 100%. The only issue is that every time I use the button right, or let the slider run automatically, there's a blank space, making me think that when the slideIndex exceeds the length, it doesn't reset the way it should.

Comment: my sample code above working 100%, is that right? if you get issue when use the button right, maybe just little wrong at increment sliderIndex, please check again the logic for increment that.

Comment: I got it working with css only, I forgot to come back and answer, sorry. I tested your code on a separate page, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign each of the images or elements containing them the same class.  Then you can grab the length of that series.  Also, you should be displaying the first one in the series by default.  I was fooling around with a method to do something like this yesterday and here is what I have, to give you an idea of how it could work:

```
<button id="right">next</button>
<hr>

<div class="hidey" id="pic1">1</div>
<div class="hidey" id="pic2">2</div>
<div class="hidey" id="pic3">3</div>
<div class="hidey" id="pic4">4</div>
```

js:

```
$(function(){
     var i = 1;
     var x = $(".hidey");
     var y = x.length;

    //shows the first image before any clicking:
     $(x[0]).show();

     $("#right").click(function() {

         if(i >= y) {
          i = 0;
         } 

     //HIDES the first pic, and all others except current index:

     $(".hidey").not( $(x)[ i ] ).hide();

    //Shows the index assigned in the first line, which is 1, which is actually the SECOND pic in the series.     

     $(x[i]).show();

    //...and the next and on.    
     i++; 
     })

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/toL33fzy/5/

Comment: Tried messing around with your method, particularly your displaying first image and hiding the rest. All of the images remain hidden, and I can't cycle through them. Also, your method is manual. I'm looking for semi-automatic with a manual override.

Comment: Yes. I'll give your code another try, and fool around with it.

Comment: Gave it another shot. The images still didn't display at all.

Comment: I'm sure you're aware there was no reference to actual images in the fiddle, but only numbers representing images, but here it is updated with kitten pics:  http://jsfiddle.net/toL33fzy/6/

Comment: Yes, I used your code as a reference, not a direct copy & paste.